# change navigation-bar style in MasterDetailview Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller

I have Xcode 4.2, and I selected the project template Master Detail view without Storybord. So how can I set navigation style and where should I add the code for this? Please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//set navigation bar tint color
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

//or to set its style
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
```

Comment: If you defined a navigation bar using IBOutlet you need to use that object name. For e.g. [yourNavigationBarObject setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

Comment: there is defult Xib and navigation already created using programicaly but in Xib i cant see the navigation bar..

Comment: self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;

Comment: are yar u u dont understand it. its created by programicaly meance dinammicly so in xib it cant see but at the time of lanching its show